# If A, B, C, and D are sets, can I proof that (A-B)-(C-D)=(A-C)-(B-D) with membership table?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to figure the problem out with membership table that, A-B=A $\cap$ ~B, but it wasn't proved that (A-B)-(C-D)=(A-C)-(B-D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(A-B)-(C-D)=(A\cap B^{\complement})\cap(C\cap D^{\complement})^{\complement}=(A\cap B^{\complement})\cap (C^{\complement}\cup D)=$$$$(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement})\cup(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap D)$$

Interchanging $B$ and $C$ in this result tells us that:
$$(A-C)-(B-D)=(A\cap C^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})\cup(A\cap C^{\complement}\cap D)$$

This shows that the sets are not equal, unless $A\cap B^{\complement}\cap D=A\cap C^{\complement}\cap D$

Answer (score 0):

Let, **A**∩**C**=Ø ∧ **B**∩**D**≠Ø ∧ **A**∩**B**=Ø ∧ **C**≠**B**-**D**.
Now, **A**-**C**≠**A**-(**B**-**D**).
Therefore, the equality is not true. In essence, the 4 relations are your counterexample. Now create sets **A**,**B**,**C**, and **D** such that the 4 relations hold and you will disprove the equality.